# VBA How to stop when setting cells equal to each other automatically changes small numbers to a percentage?

Tags: vba, excel

When I am setting two cells to each other, if the number is too small it automatically sets the receiving cell to a percentage and not the actual number, how do I avoid this?

Comment: Do you have some code, and examples of when it does and doesn't happen?

Comment: `Cell(x,y).NumberFormat = "0.##########"` with `#'s` equal to the max number of digits past the decimal?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, I just selected the entire range of numbers once they had been pasted and selected them before doing:

`Selection.NumberFormat = "General"`